# how do I copy arrays using a vectorized loop?

Tags: c, optimization, vectorization

I would like to vectorize a simple array copy.  The arrays are handed in as a float* with an int for the size.  I check the sizing beforehand then run the copy:

```
int i;
float *vec;
float *tab;

for(i = x->x_start; i < x->x_end; i++)
  vec[i] = tab[i];
```

I've tried mucking about with this very simple statement, but I can't seem to get it to auto-vectorize.  I tried `restrict` to no effect, and played with `__builtin_assume_aligned(vec, 16)`

Comment: What compiler? What platform? Have you considered using intrinsics?

Comment: What about just using `memcpy`?  That should be optimized to whatever will run best on your platform.

Comment: On any reasonably sane platform, `memcpy` should already be vectorized (unless there's an even faster means to copy on the platform, in which case `memcpy` should use that).

Comment: Are you certain x_ start/x_end are correct? Is X in scope? (I assume this is a function, was it passed properly?)

Also, the above guys are right, use memcpy.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the code? Maybe it already uses vector instructions - my gcc compiles certainly does, if I give it half a chance [half a chance means -m64 compile or -msse2].

Comment: The CPU does not really have to do much here. I would not be surprized if it idles around for the memory/cache to return the data and write it back. If you want to optimize for speed, try to reduce the number of times you have to walk through this float buffer (if it's large enough to not fit into the cache) in your program.